# How can I add a rake command alias to OS X .bash_profile?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I am trying to add this rails alias to my .bash_profile.

```
alias migrate='bin/rake db:migrate db:test:clone’
```

If I enter the command in the terminal, it will last and work fine until I start a new session.

If I add the command to `.bash_profile` and do `source .bash_profile` I get

```
-bash: alias: db:migrate: not found
-bash: alias: db:test:clone”: not found
```

The rest of my `.bash_profile` is:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
PATH="/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
alias migrate=“bin/rake db:migrate db:test:clone”
```

This must be a simple error on my part, but 20 minutes of googling and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit your .bash_profile and add the correct quotes.
You probably did a cut-and-paste from the web and OSX helpully changed the `" ... "` to `“ ... ”`

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong quote characters.
Notice the difference in quotes characters from this

```
alias migrate=“bin/rake db:migrate db:test:clone”
```

to this

```
alias migrate="bin/rake db:migrate db:test:clone"
```

Also you're using a relative path for rake "bin/rake" which is unrelated to the error you're getting but will cause other problems. Make sure rake is in your path and just use "rake" in the alias.

```
alias migrate="rake db:migrate db:test:clone"
```